Metaprogramming: Typedef of std::function argument list
I'm building a plugin for an engine, and I'm aiming to do as much templating and metaprogramming as I can because I will be making a version of this plugin for a different engine, as well.
To start with the first version, I have a set of function objects that are declared based on an API of function pointers (the pointers are removed for pure function signature). This is meant so I can register my function objects as callbacks to the engine's signals, such as OnMissionLoad.  With the function objects declared, next I need to build the functions that will be assigned into the function objects. This is where I'm trying to let the compiler do the work, but failing. I want to typedef the argument list of the function objects so I can make the function and pass in that typedef to automatically get the argument list without manually writing all the types. The types can be varied as are the number of arguments.
API Function object
std::function<std::remove_pointer_t<OnMissionLoad_Func>> OnMissionLoad;
-> std::function<APIResult(const char*)> OnMissionLoad;

EDIT: another function
std::function<std::remove_pointer_t<OnMouseButtonPressed_Func> OnMouseButtonPressed;
-> std::function<APIResult(WindowID window_id, ButtonID_v1 button_id, int32_t client_x, int32_t client_y, BOOL handled);

class Plugin
{
protected:
        // Code I found online
        template <class T> struct std_func_param {};
        template <class R, class T> struct std_func_param<std::function<R(T)>> { using type = T; };
        template <class T> using std_func_param_t = typename std_func_param<T>::type;

        APIResult OnMissionLoad(std_func_param_t<decltype(APIFunctions::MissionListenerAPI::OnMissionLoad)> args) {}
        APIResult OnMouseButtonPressed(std_func_param_t<decltype(APIFunctions::OSServiceListenerAPI::OnMouseButtonPressed)> args) {}
};

The above works, because there is only one argument in the list. However, if I write another with two variables in the argument list, I will get
Error   C2794   'type': is not a member of any direct or indirect base class of 'Plugin::std_func_param<std::function<APIResult(WindowID,ButtonID_v1,int32_t,int32_t,BOOL)>>'

Error   C2938   'Plugin::std_func_param_t' : Failed to specialize alias template

Is there a way in C++20 to specialize a variable number of arguments so I can do as I did with the OnMissionLoad and effectively pass in the name of the function object to break it down to its argument list?

The above works - Could you please create a complete compileable example that demonstrates how this machinery is supposed to be used?

Creating a logical pipeline. Function object is registered to engine signal callback. Function object is assigned a function to run. Engine signals get pumped into the plugin through that pipeline.

Suppose you can write the declaration for multiple parameters somehow. How are you going to use the args in your function definition?

That is a very good question. However I can expand them is my only answer. I've seen code that looks like variadic templates into tuples, but I'm really just throwing words out because I haven't tried writing templating at this level. I don't even know if this is possible, and ultimately if I must, I can just read the API headers and write out the argument types manually. I was just hoping that I could create a shortcut to the starting API changing, since it is possible for it to change in the future.

If you change your function to take a tuple instead and use std::get in the function definition, it is not hard to extract the signature of the tuple using techniques similar to what is present in your question. On the other hand, it is possible to forward the function signature from a function to another by using proper typedefs, but then the question is how you can actually use the args in your definition, as I asked in my last question.

Okay, sounds like I'm trying to take this step one too far and I'll just have to copy the origin header function signatures to do what I need it to do. I was trying to see how far I could push it with the standard, to keep my knowledge up.

If you can template the whole plugin class you can do this:
template<typename Function>
class Plugin;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
class Plugin<std::function<R(Args...)>> {
    APIResult OnMissionLoad(Args... args);
};

using SpecificPlugin = Plugin<decltype(VBSAPIFunctions::MissionListenerAPI::OnMissionLoad)>;


What about OnMouseButtonPressed?

@Evg You can just add a new template parameter: example

Unclear what you want, but for declaration, following works:
class Plugin
{
protected:
    decltype(APIFunctions::OnMissionLoad) OnMissionLoad;
    decltype(APIFunctions::OnMouseButtonPressed) OnMouseButtonPressed;
};

but you will have to write the definition "manually":
APIResult Plugin::OnMissionLoad(const char* s){ /* ... */ }
APIResult Plugin::OnMouseButtonPressed(int x, int y){ /* ... */ }

Demo
If you want an easy way to forward a class member function to a free function,
you might be interested by
template <auto F>
struct Func;

template <typename R, typename... Ts, R (*F)(Ts...)>
struct Func<F>
{
    R operator()(Ts... args) const { return F(std::forward<Ts>(args)...); }
};

class Plugin
{
public:
    Func<APIFunctions::OnMissionLoad> OnMissionLoad;
    Func<APIFunctions::OnMouseButtonPressed> OnMouseButtonPressed;
};

Demo
